# What language is this and what does it means?

Tags: japanese, language-identification

I have this kind of flag since i was born, it was given by some japanese friends of my father as a gift for my birth. But today neither me or my father know the meaning of what's written in it.

Someone knows in what language is it written and what does it means?

horizontal orientation
[image: horizontal orientation]

or if it's inverted
[image: or if it's inverted]

in vertical orientation
[image: in vertical orientation:]

zoom at the caligraphy
[image: zoom at the caligraphy]

Comment: You're holding it sideways, rotate the first picture 90 degrees to the left. The ぬ is very easy to identify so I'd assume it's Japanese.

Comment: This isn't really a linguistics question (nor is it a question suitable for Japanese SE), but I answered it because I wonder about the motif of the repeated syllabary ぬ. If anyone else disagrees that it falls under our purview, feel free to vote to close.

Comment: Thanks jogloran, i agree with you but this was the proper way i found to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says (vertically, top to bottom) [市川團十郎](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichikawa_Danj%C5%ABr%C5%8D), which is the stage name of numerous generations of Kabuki actors.

I'm not sure of the significance of the ぬ motif -- that's just a syllable from the hiragana syllabary with no clear independent meaning.

The circle is an [円相](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ens%C5%8D), a brush-drawn circle which is meditated upon.

The third object looks like a sickle, but again I'm not sure of its significance.